# How to switch to new Postgres instance after installing new version of it?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I develop a Nodejs app with sequelize used. I have been using 9.6 and just installed 10.6 and also copied the database to the new version (so right now I have 2 copies of it, one for each server/version).

However, my app still uses the old one. I am not sure how to change that. Is it via code or should I just stop somehow the old server running and start the new one? I use pgAdmin by the way.

This is my config.json that sequelize uses:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "364200",
    "database": "userbase",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5433, // was 5432
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "364200",
    "database": "userbase",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5433, // was 5432
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "364200",
    "database": "userbase",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5433, // was 5432
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

index.js (sequelize)

```
sequelize = new Sequelize('userbase', 'postgres', '364200', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '5433' // <--- ADD THIS HERE
  dialect: 'postgres',

});
```

EDIT: Fixed it with @Chiller's help in comments

Comment: If you have two PostgreSQL on your system, and planning to use them both, then you should use different port for each one

Comment: @Chiller Indeed, I just saw that the new version has a different port number, so I updated the code I posted. However, sequelize still uses the old version (running at another port). Any idea why?

Comment: in Index.js file i think you should add port: 'new port' when creating a new db connection

Comment: @Chiller That's it, thanks!

Comment: Rather than edit your Question with the solution, post an Answer, then accept it (click big green checkmark). Posting an Answer to your own Question is perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow.